# Micro-service deploy using helm

Tags: microservices, kubernetes-helm

I am totally new at helm deployment. I want to deploy a microservice application using helm. There are a couple of services including consul and database. How can I configure so that consul and database services are deployed first and other services will be deployed later

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in your services to check that the services it depends are available and that you can connect to them.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
  - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup mydb.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done"]
```

References:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/